# Как найти спецсимволы, кроме указанных?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Хотел бы найти в файле все запрещенные символы, то есть те, что не указаны как разрешенные.
Разрешенные символы:

```
Aa-Zz
Аа-Яя
0-9
()-_.,|%;:='"+
```

Пробую через, даже без спецсимволов: `grep -r [^Aa-ZzАа-Яя0-9]` , всё равно находит всё подряд:

```
$ grep -r [^a-zA-Z0-9]
test-.txt:﻿1
test_.txt:﻿123
test_.txt:абв
test_.txt:abcdefg
test_.txt:32-09ejr-0wfji094f
test_.txt:12dsgffarga wortw9r8gaupgnr485
test_.txt:%
test_.txt:$
test_.txt:#
test_.txt:№
```

Comment: ``[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я0-9]*`` ?

Comment: Всё работает согласно вашему регулярному выражению. Почитайте про а) ключ `-v` и б) «жадность» регулярных выражений. @Эникейщик, и вы тоже.

Comment: @0andriy да я знаком. А диапазонов a-Z и а-Я не существует

Comment: Команда `grep -r [^a-zA-Z0-9]` у меня не матчит строки 123 или abcdefg (GNU grep 3.4, Убунту). Это точно прямая цитата из терминала, а не сконструированный вывод?

Comment: оказалось дело в символе переноса строки \n - иногда он тоже учитывается + какие особенности с моим локальным grep